# MS Teams locked onto an old organisation

Tags: apt, configuration, microsoft-teams

MS Teams is locked onto an old organisation. You want to switch to a new one. What to do?

All you can find by searching are some irrelevant "answers" by "contributors" on Microsoft forums. You are pulling your hair out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt purge teams
rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft\ Teams/
rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft\ Teams\ -\ Preview/
sudo apt install teams
```